# Angular- How to show an input field based on multiple select option?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I wish to show the checkin and checkout input field based on multiple select days option. For example,
select the Monday and Tuesday will show the two checkin and checkout input field let users to fill the time range for selected days.

Here is my code.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Active Days</label>
            <ng-select [items]="days" name="days"
                       bindLabel="id"
                       autofocus
                       loadingText="Loading ..."
                       [multiple]=true
                       bindValue="id"
                       placeholder="Select Active Days"
                       [(ngModel)]="attendanceProfile.days">
            </ng-select>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Check In Time</label>
            <input autocomplete="off" atp-time-picker type="text" class="form-control" 
                   name="checkInTime"
                   id="checkInTime" [(ngModel)]="attendanceProfile.checkInTime.InTime"
                   placeholder="Select CheckIn Time"/>  
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Check Out Time</label>
            <input autocomplete="off" atp-time-picker type="text" class="form-control" 
                   name="checkOutTime"
                   id="checkOutTime" [(ngModel)]="attendanceProfile.checkOutTime"
                   placeholder="Select CheckOut Time"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i really understand you need to show input fields only when somedays are selected, for this you need just to use ngIf condition like :

```
*ngIf="attendanceProfile?.days?.length"
```

**Example :**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Active Days</label>
        <ng-select [items]="days" name="days"
                   bindLabel="id"
                   autofocus
                   loadingText="Loading ..."
                   [multiple]=true
                   bindValue="id"
                   placeholder="Select Active Days"
                   [(ngModel)]="attendanceProfile.days">
        </ng-select>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="attendanceProfile?.days?.length" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Check In Time</label>
        <input autocomplete="off" atp-time-picker type="text" class="form-control" 
               name="checkInTime"
               id="checkInTime" [(ngModel)]="attendanceProfile.checkInTime.InTime"
               placeholder="Select CheckIn Time"/>  
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Check Out Time</label>
        <input autocomplete="off" atp-time-picker type="text" class="form-control" 
               name="checkOutTime"
               id="checkOutTime" [(ngModel)]="attendanceProfile.checkOutTime"
               placeholder="Select CheckOut Time"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```